# Using a UIwebview app to get the UID from the device for apple push notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, uiwebview, push-notification

I have a web app which I need to send apple push notifications to. I was thinking if I set up a login screen  specifically for the web view to point to, which included a request for the device UUID on post, for the purpose of apple push notifications. So can you ask the device for its UUID from a page being viewed in ui.webview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your question. Firstly apple deprecated the UDID, which was never used for push notifications anyway. You get a push token when you sign up for push notifications.

Secondly you can't send push notifications to a web app or a webpage running in an iOS app, you need to implement this in objective-c in an iOS app. There is no other way around it.

I suggest you read the apple docs / tutorials on this as there is a lot to learn. Heres the main overview: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you have cleared a few things up for me. Now I know why I couldn't find the answers I was looking for :)

Comment: @Benswana no problem, don't forget to mark top answer / upvote so others facing the same issue will know what solved your question and I get the rep points for putting in the time